# htaccess redirects invalid request to home page not 404

Tags: htaccess, 404-error

Trying to work out how to get Wordpress / .htaccess to show a 404 error page for invalid requests.

With a default WP `.htaccess` file a request like

```
https://example.com/?exam=testing.html
```

will redirect to the home page but it retains the invalid request as the URL.

The issue is that Google is treating this as a 'successful' load of a page that is a hacked 'exam papers site' page and listing the site as hacked.

Trying any invalid page request gives the same result like:

```
https://example.com/an-invalid-page
```

Options seem to be :

1. get `.htaccess` to drop the request when redirecting to the Home Page so that the URL is only the `https://example.com/`  - however this is still incorrectly suggesting a successful page from the request
2. prefer to see a 404, 403 or even 401 to clearly show that it was an invalid request and present an appropriate error page, so that Google tests will get an appropriate result, and humans creating errors will also be told.

However, trying to search results for the above provide a plethora of pages explaining how to avoid 404 errors, and not how to have them.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hello @thowden, welcome to WPSE. I'm not an .htaccess expert, but I can suggest you [a plugin for easy redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/), while editing and updating .htaccess every time is a tedious work.

Comment: `https://example.com/?exam=testing.html` _is_ the URL for the homepage (there is no URL-path, just a query string), so seeing the homepage for such a request is "normal" (however, there should be no "redirect" that you mention?). `https://example.com/an-invalid-page` on the other hand is entirely different. If you are seeing the homepage for such a request then this is entirely within WordPress (assuming you have pretty permalinks enabled) - this later request has nothing to do with `.htaccess`.